# How can i optimize this query for sql for counting response

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

I have a table of response from the question and when i try to count the number of response over the question by query for creating a graph it took 65seconds to load

so can please guide me someone how can we optimize this query

```
SELECT
vr.question_id,
(SELECT COUNT(response) FROM visitors_response  WHERE question_id = vr.question_id AND response = 5 ) AS one_star,
(SELECT COUNT(response) FROM visitors_response  WHERE question_id = vr.question_id AND response = 4 ) AS two_star,
(SELECT COUNT(response) FROM visitors_response  WHERE question_id = vr.question_id AND response = 3 ) AS three_star,
(SELECT COUNT(response) FROM visitors_response  WHERE question_id = vr.question_id AND response = 2 ) AS four_star,
(SELECT COUNT(response) FROM visitors_response  WHERE question_id = vr.question_id AND response = 1 ) AS five_star,
(SELECT AVG(response)   FROM visitors_response  WHERE question_id = vr.question_id ) AS average 
FROM visitors_response vr
JOIN questions q ON q.id = vr.question_id 
JOIN survey s ON s.id = q.survey_id
WHERE s.user_id = 101 AND s.status = 'active' 
GROUP BY vr.question_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
vr.question_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN response = 5 THEN response END) AS one_star,
COUNT(CASE WHEN response = 4 THEN response END) AS two_star,
COUNT(CASE WHEN response = 3 THEN response END) AS three_star,
COUNT(CASE WHEN response = 2 THEN response END) AS four_star,
COUNT(CASE WHEN response = 1 THEN response END) AS five_star,
AVG(response) AS average 
FROM visitors_response vr
JOIN questions q ON q.id = vr.question_id 
JOIN survey s ON s.id = q.survey_id
WHERE s.user_id = 101 AND s.status = 'active' 
GROUP BY vr.question_id
```

Or by using `SUM` instead of `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
vr.question_id,
SUM(response = 5) AS one_star,
SUM(response = 4) AS two_star,
SUM(response = 3) AS three_star,
SUM(response = 2) AS four_star,
SUM(response = 1) AS five_star,
AVG(response) AS average 
FROM visitors_response vr
JOIN questions q ON q.id = vr.question_id 
JOIN survey s ON s.id = q.survey_id
WHERE s.user_id = 101 AND s.status = 'active' 
GROUP BY vr.question_id
```

Comment: Check the results.  `JOIN` may inflate the number of rows, then the counting occurs _before_ the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF() function inside any aggregate function. The trick is COUNT() counts not null values only, so put NULL into "else" part. Like here:

```sql
SELECT 
  COUNT(IF(response=1,1,NULL)) AS one_star,
  COUNT(IF(response=2,1,NULL)) AS two_star,
  COUNT(IF(response=3,1,NULL)) AS three_star,
  COUNT(IF(response=4,1,NULL)) AS four_star,
  COUNT(IF(response=5,1,NULL)) AS five_star,
  AVG(response) AS average
FROM visitors_response vr
JOIN questions q ON q.id = vr.question_id 
JOIN survey s ON s.id = q.survey_id
WHERE s.user_id = 101 AND s.status = 'active' 
GROUP BY vr.question_id
```

or you can do the same via "OR" operation:

```sql
  COUNT(response=1 OR NULL) AS one_star,
```

As for me, it is the shortest and most understandable option.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any query optimization questions you should provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` statements for each table involved in the query.

That said, if the following indexes don't exist, add them to your tables:

```
survey: (user_id,status)
questions: (survey_id)
visitor_responses: (question_id,response)
```

The above indexes assume `id` on the `survey` and `questions` table is the primary key of each table, respectively.

Report back on how that improved performance, and include the up to date `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` statements for each of those tables, so we can help make sure you don't have any redundant indexes now.

If performance is not under 1 second, or any other threshold you care to beat, also include a current `EXPLAIN` plan.